# Custom Marker on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am  working On Google map in android and Image not displayed when i set in My customView Below in function createCustomMarker().Please recommend me if doing some wrong. But I set the drawable from  drawable folder then displayed But not from String url.

```
 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap
        mMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16.0f))
        mMap?.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
        mMap?.setMinZoomPreference(6.0f)
        mMap?.setMaxZoomPreference(21.0f)
        mMap?.isIndoorEnabled = false

        
        mMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        val coordinate =
            LatLng(prefs?.current_lati?.toDouble()!!, prefs?.current_longi?.toDouble()!!) //Store these lat lng values somewhere. These should be constant.

        val location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            coordinate, 15f
        )

        for(i in 0..arraylist?.size){

            var lat=arraylist?.get(i)?.latitude
            var longi=arraylist?.get(i)?.longitude

      mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(lat!!,longi!!)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createCustomMarker( requireContext(),arraylist?.get(i)!!.image))))}

mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(locationArrayList!![i]))

mMap!!.animateCamera(location)

}


 private fun createCustomMarker(context: Context, userImage: String): Bitmap {
        val marker: View =
            (context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater).inflate(
                R.layout.lay_cutom_marker,
                null
            )
        val markerImage: ImageView = marker.findViewById(R.id.img_res)
        var bmp: Bitmap? = null
      // val url = URL(userImage)
       Glide.with(context).load(userImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user).error(R.drawable.ic_user).into(markerImage)
        

        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            context.display?.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)
        } else {
            requireActivity().windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        }
        marker.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(52, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        marker.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)
        marker.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels)
        marker.buildDrawingCache()
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            marker.measuredWidth, marker.measuredHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bmp)
        marker.draw(canvas)
        return bmp
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of you make icon after that image is loading in drawable as you load an image. you need to increase wait time until image has been loaded after that do all stuff regarding iconGenerator.